# Why doesn't librsvg doesn't export the black paths in a PNG?

Tags: svg, librsvg

[Here](http://imgh.us/WK.svg) is an SVG image I want to convert to PNG with librsvg in my program.

This is a PNG version of the SVG exported from Inkscape:

[image]

This is a bitmap of the same SVG exported with librsvg:

[image]

Only the white portions of the image are exported. The black portions, despite being well-defined in the background, appear transparent.

This problem occurs whether I use the librsvg API or the program `rsvg-convert`. You can use the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org) to see that the SVG's markup is valid.

I notice the same thing happens in the thumbnails of the SVGs in my file browser. Perhaps they're using librsvg?

Answer (score 0):

Upon digging into the files I discovered that, for some reason, the fill of the black portion was set to `"fill:currentColor"`. I don't know where that came from, but changing it to `"fill:#000000"` fixed the problem.